# With R, iterate over data frames, perform math operations on each one, append results in new data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

I have a huge data frame (A) in R that looks like this:

```
Letters   Frequency   Numbers
a         0.15        1
b         0.67        2
c         0.85        7
d         0.4         3
```

I would like to first divide A into 4 data frames according to the range of values of the "Frequency" column (4 frequency bins of size 0.25), which go from 0 to 1, so that I obtain:

```
A1 [0, 0.25]

Letters   Frequency   Numbers
a         0.15        1

A2 [0.25, 0.5]

Letters   Frequency   Numbers
d         0.4         3

A3 [0.5, 0.75]

Letters   Frequency   Numbers
b         0.67        2

A4 [0.75, 1]

Letters   Frequency   Numbers
c         0.85        7
```

In an iterative way and following the order of the frequency bins, I would like to perform math operations in A1, A2, A3 and A4 (e.g., op1 = Numbers - 2; op2 = Numbers * 10) and create a data frame B with the appended results:

```
B

bin            op1    op2   
[0, 0.25]      -1     10 
[0.25, 0.5]     1     30 
[0.5, 0.75]     0     20 
[0.75, 1]       5     70
```

I guess I don't need to create A1, A2, A3 and A4 (ideally I would like to work only with A) and that there is a more elegant way of getting B by iterating through the frequency bins directly, but I created them in this example to clearly explain the principle. I think this can be done with lapply, but I am not sure how. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R method with the split-apply-combine methodology is

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dd, findInterval(dd$Frequency, c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1))),
                      function(i) within(i, { # create variables, remove Numbers
                                         op1 <- Numbers - 2
                                         op2 <- Numbers * 10
                                         Numbers <- NULL})))
```

This returns

```
  Letters Frequency op2 op1
1       a      0.15  10  -1
2       d      0.40  30   1
3       b      0.67  20   0
4       c      0.85  70   5
```

Here, `findInterval` bins the observations based on Frequency, `split` splits the data.frame based on these bins and orders the data accordingly, `lapply` and `within` are used to construct the new variables for each group.

Comment: Thank you very much @Imo. It would be great to have your feedback on the last comment I posted.

Comment: If you are referring to your comment in mr-flick's answer, I am having trouble visualizing it. From my second reading, it seems different enough to post as a new question with a good example illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple `group_by` in dplyr. For example with your data.

```
dd<-read.table(text="Letters   Frequency   Numbers
a         0.15        1
b         0.67        2
c         0.85        7
d         0.4         3", header=T)
```

You can run

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
    group_by(bin=cut(Frequency, breaks=seq(0,1,by=.25))) %>% 
    transmute(op1=Numbers-2, op2=Numbers*10) %>% 
    arrange(bin)
```

We use `cut()` to create the binning groups and then use `transmute()` to create the new columns (while dropping the old).

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, it also worked your way. May I ask you how would you do it iteratively (or with dplyr) if I wanted to perform these math operations on sub dataframes that contain all rows that in a certain column (e.g. "Letters") have specific words, such as "genic". The problem is that these words come in a context, such as "genic/intronic/missense", and therefore I cannot group_by them by "genic" alone. I know how to extract these sub dataframes using grepl and doing it manually, but I am not able to do it in an elegant way. Thanks very much.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean. You should create a new post with a reproducible example with sample input and desired output as you did in this question.